# Join 2 tables without create table

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

Have a basic query that I need help with.

I have 2 tables, `Table A` and `Table B` which I want to join.

I want to put a column from `Table B` onto `Table A` using common Key.

The catch is that instead of using `CREATE TABLE Table C`, I want to modify Table A directly with my new column.

What do I add to my existing code?

```
SELECT *, Table A.Column as NewColumn from Table A
LEFT JOIN Table B
ON Table A.Key = Table B.key;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do this in two steps

Step 1 Create a newColumn in the [Table A] to take the data

Step 2 - Update the data using the expression below where [newColumn] is the name of the new column from (1) and [SomeExpression] is the value that you want in there.

```
Update [Table A]
Set [Table A].[NewColumn] = [someExpresssion]
from [Table A]
LEFT JOIN [Table B]
ON [Table A].Key = [Table B].key;
```

Comment: Thanks! I haven't encountered the Update syntax before this is helpful :)

Comment: Could you clarify what [someExpression] would refer to?

Comment: [SomeExpression] refers to what value you want to put in there. You can specify many different sorts of values and expressions. e.g. a constant or another column or even values from another table. Its pretty flexible. Its your new column in this instance so [TABLE A].[NewColumn] = [TABLE B].[Column] or [TABLE B].[NewColumn] = [TABLE A].[Column] depending on which way you decided to move the data.